# moving legacy app to new device

Tags: applications, file-transfer, apk, data-transfer

So I recently bought a new phone and there's this app I have on my old device that is not available in the play store anymore and that I should nonetheless like to move to my new device.

I'm confident that if I searched for it on the net, I'd be able to find the .apk of the app.

*However*, I also know that after installation, the app used to connect to a server to download additional files necessary for the app to work (once). That server doesn't exist, anymore. The data, though, must of course still be on my old device, somewhere.

Where do I find that data and how can I move the app?

Note: neither device is rooted.

Note: I cannot root the new device

Comment: Titanium backup and/or ADB backup. ADB backup definitely works without root, but you need 4.3+. You'll need to extract the app data along with the .apk. Ti+ requires root, but it can import ADB backups (.ab files) if you root the new device and the old device is 4.3+, perfect scenario. Look at [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55859/adb-restore-across-different-devices-android-versions) for details. You can try an `adb restore` on the new device from the old one to avoid rooting, but that will likely cause persistent ANR dialogs and maybe a bricked device.

Comment: I should add that I cannot root the new device because that would break a critical app that intentionally stops working on rooted devices.

Comment: Dang. Here's what I have in mind, then. Extract the apk and app data from the old device. If the data is on /sdcard, then you've wasted our time! Just copy it. Else, If you can root it without resetting it, then root and use Ti+ (older devices usually are open to one-click-root apps -- Framaroot, Towelroot, Poot, etc). If it's new enough to have Jellybean or better, use ADB backup and extract the specific app data. On the new device, install the app. If the data was in /sdcard, just paste it. Else, you'll have to mimic the server on your Wifi network (ouch). Mimic the IP address and files.